# $\max\{X_1,X_2,\cdots ,X_n\}\xrightarrow{a.s.}x^*_F$

Tags: probability, convergence

I have the following question at hand:

> Let $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ be an **iid** sequence of random variables with common distribution function $F$ ; such that $x^*_F:=\sup\{x\ : F(x)<1\}<\infty.$ Show that $\max\{X_1,X_2,\cdots ,X_n\}$ converges almost surely to $x^*_F.$

How to attack this problem?

Comment: This appears to be a textbook-style problem. Please read the `self-study` [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), and edit to either more clearly indicate your thoughts on the problem and where you run into difficulties -- and add the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum $M_n:=\max(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ has distribution $F^n(x)$. Fix $\epsilon>0$, so:
\begin{align*}
P(|M_n-x_F^*|>\epsilon)&=P(M_n-x_F^*>\epsilon)+P(M_n-x_F< -\epsilon)\\
&\leq 1-F^n(x_F^*+\epsilon)+F^n(x_F^*-\epsilon)\\
&=1-1+z^n,
\end{align*}

where $z<1$. Thus:

$$\sum_nP(|M_n-x_F^*|>\epsilon)\leq \sum_n z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}<\infty.$$

Now use the fact that when the Borel Cantelli Lemma holds for all $\epsilon>0$, it follows that $M_n\rightarrow x_F^*$ almost surely.

Comment: I know that $\sum_1^\infty P(A_n)\lt \infty\implies P(lim sup (A_n)=0$. How to derive Almost sure convergence?

Comment: @Qwerty: see 19 to 22 of this: http://www.randomservices.org/random/prob/Convergence.html

Comment: So Is the following correct? $$\forall\epsilon>0 \ ,\  \sum\limits_1^\infty P(|M_n-x^*_F|>\epsilon)<\infty\\\implies  \forall\epsilon>0 \ ,\  P(\limsup_{n\to\infty}|M_n-x^*_F|>\epsilon)=0\\\implies \forall\epsilon>0 \ ,\ P(|M_n-x^*_F|>\epsilon \text{ for infinitely many } n )=0\\\implies P(M_n\to x^*_F \text{ as } n\to\infty)=1\\\implies M_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} x^*_F$$